# Algolia / Wordpress: Index is pushing to wp_searcheable_posts but not other index

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm using the Algolia Wordpress plugin, and looking to add some ACF fields to my Algolia indexes.

The below code is from the Algolia documentation, the problem I'm having with is it's not updating the Algolia index "wp_posts_doctor" which as you can guess indexes from a custom post type named "doctor".

Below looks pretty straight-forward, but obviously the first filter isn't firing. I've tried many combinations, but not sure what the correct syntax is.

I replaced *post* with *doctor*, _doctor_post ...no dice.

DOes anyone know what the proper convention ? Thank you.

add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', '_provider_attributes', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_searchable_post_shared_attributes', '_provider_attributes', 10, 2 );

Answer (score 0):

So the default filter, does not need modifying. Oddly enough to push up a specific index for a custom post type, I went into Algolia Search > Autocomplete in WP admin, and clicked re-index for the relevant post type. That's all it took.

```
add_filter( 'algolia_post_shared_attributes', '_provider_attributes', 10, 2 );
```